# Appcelerator - Turning off warnings

Tags: javascript, warnings, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Does anyone know how to turn off warnings during the build process. While I like warnings, minified javascript code makes it go crazy, and it will not go past the warning stage to build the app, and often stalls. Is there a switch somewhere to turn them off?

Comment: You mean the JSLint errors because non of those should stop the build process unless it's a fatal error and not just a warning.

Comment: Yes, jSLint, and it does indeed stall if there are too many errors. It just doesn't build. A bug, and a very annoying one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Titanium Developer you can turn off or modify jslint by updating compiler.js

Below a link that details how to do this.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/27621/just-started---want-to-use-googles-closure-tools

Please note if you are using the new Titanium Studio this might not work.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. They have a line which states `// if it looks like jQuery, skip it ... too many warnings that are OK`. In this file (compiler.js), I can tell it to ignore certain files which I am including. Very handy. Thanks.